# Strange Maven Java Could not find or load main class issue

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

I'm having a strange problem with my Maven build for a project. For some reason it gives me an error when building (Run As -> Java Application in eclipse) that says "Could not find or load main class".

The strange part is, the manifest in the pom is 100% correct.

The process is, Clean, Build, Run As -> Java Application in Eclipse. Works fine.

Run As -> Maven Build... -> clean install. Generates jar that gives main class error.

Back to Eclipse Run As -> Java Application: Now also gives the main class error until cleaned and built again.

Does this sound familiar to anyone??

Comment: I manually rebuilt the project into a fresh maven project and it now works. I have no idea what could be screwed up in the eclipse project settings.

Comment: Delete the `.project`, `.classpath`, `.settings` folder in your project and reimport into Eclipse...sometimes the m2e has problems...

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your project(s) --> Maven --> Update Project...

Comment: I've tried that multiple times. Unfortunately to no effect.